# HSM generate self-signed cert report "wrapping key handle invalid" error

Tags: certificate, pkcs#11

Using HSM (with `PKCS11` standard API) to generate self-signed cert reports "wrapping key handle invalid" error (Error Code `113`, `CKR_WRAPPING_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID`). This happens both when using GUI `ctbrowser` tool to generate or using code similar to their demo.

Here is a code example to reproduce the issue, it generate a RSA keypair and then attempt to generate a self-signed cert with them.

```
int main()
{
    int rv;
    CK_CHAR pwd[] = "password";
    static char pubkeyLabel[256]="demoPub";
    static char prvkeyLabel[256]="demoPrv";
    static CK_BYTE id[256];
    static CK_BBOOL isTok = TRUE;
    static CK_BBOOL True = TRUE;
    static CK_BBOOL False = FALSE;

    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPubKey;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phPubKey = &hPubKey;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hSignerKey;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phSignerKey = &hSignerKey;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hCert;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phCert = &hCert;
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism = { 0, NULL, 0 };
    static CK_SIZE mBits=2048;

    static char edate[] = {'2','0','2','0','1','2','3','1'};
    static char certLabel[128]="demo_cert";
    static char subject[256]="C=XX,ST=XX,L=XX,O=MEOW,OU=HSM,CN=TESTCERT";

    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
      {CKA_TOKEN, &isTok, 1},
      {CKA_PRIVATE, &False, 1},
      {CKA_LABEL, pubkeyLabel, sizeof(pubkeyLabel)},
      {CKA_SUBJECT_STR, subject, sizeof(subject)},
      {CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &mBits, sizeof(mBits)},
      {CKA_ENCRYPT, &False, 1},
      {CKA_VERIFY, &True, 1},
      {CKA_WRAP, &False, 1},
      {CKA_DERIVE, &True, 1},
      {CKA_EXTRACTABLE, &True, 1},
      {CKA_EXPORTABLE, &True, 1}
    };
    CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] = {
      {CKA_TOKEN, &isTok, 1},
      {CKA_LABEL, prvkeyLabel, sizeof(prvkeyLabel)},
      {CKA_PRIVATE, &True, 1},
      {CKA_SUBJECT_STR, subject, sizeof(subject)},
      {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
      {CKA_SENSITIVE, &True, 1},
      {CKA_DECRYPT, &False, 1},
      {CKA_SIGN, &True, 1},
      {CKA_UNWRAP, &True, 1},
      {CKA_WRAP, &False, 1},
      {CKA_EXTRACTABLE, &False, 1},
      {CKA_EXPORTABLE, &False, 1}
    };

    CK_ATTRIBUTE certTemplate[] = {
      {CKA_TOKEN, &True, 1},
      {CKA_PRIVATE, &False, 1},
      {CKA_LABEL, certLabel, sizeof(certLabel)},
      {CKA_SUBJECT_STR, subject, sizeof(subject)},
      {CKA_ISSUER_STR, subject, sizeof(subject)},
      {CKA_END_DATE, edate, sizeof(edate)},
      {CKA_EXTRACTABLE, &True, 1},
      {CKA_EXPORTABLE, &True, 1}
    };

    printf("Generate cert %s from %s, signed by %s.\n", certLabel, pubkeyLabel, prvkeyLabel);
    rv = C_Initialize(NULL_PTR);
    if ( rv ) return rv;

    rv = C_OpenSession(0, CKF_RW_SESSION|CKF_SERIAL_SESSION, NULL, NULL, &hSession);

    rv = C_Login(hSession, CKU_USER, pwd, 8);

    publicKeyTemplate[2].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)pubkeyLabel);
    publicKeyTemplate[3].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)subject)+1;
    privateKeyTemplate[1].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)prvkeyLabel);
    privateKeyTemplate[3].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)subject)+1;
    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN;
    rv = C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession, &mechanism,
                           publicKeyTemplate, NUMITEMS(publicKeyTemplate),
                           privateKeyTemplate, NUMITEMS(privateKeyTemplate),
                           phPubKey, phSignerKey);
    printf("Keypair generated with rv=%x\n", rv);

    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS;
    rv = C_SignInit(hSession, &mechanism, hSignerKey);
    printf("cert signer initiated with rv=%x\n", rv);
    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_ENCODE_X_509;
    certTemplate[2].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)certLabel);
    certTemplate[3].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)subject)+1;
    certTemplate[4].valueLen = (CK_SIZE)strlen((char*)subject)+1;
    rv = C_DeriveKey(hSession, &mechanism,
                     hPubKey,
                     certTemplate, NUMITEMS(certTemplate),
                     phCert);
    printf("cert generation finished with rv=%x\n", rv);

    return 0;
}
```

Since the entire process do not involve any wrapping, I have no clue on how to debug this. Does anyone has any idea what's wrong with it? (NOTE: slot is pre-existing and initialized.)

Comment: I suggest you contact the manufacturer of the HSM and ask for support.

Comment: You are setting a lot of attributes explicitly, including `CKA_WRAP` and `CKA_UNWRAP` as well as the EXTRACTABLE and EXPORTABLE flags (which may require a wrapping key). Maybe you should remove those attributes and try again. If that works you can set them again and see which one causes the failure

Comment: @MaartenBodewes `CKA_WRAP` `CKA_UNWRAP` are attribute, disabling them indicates that they will not be used as wrapping keys to export other keys. `EXTRACTABLE` is needed for pubkey or else the value cannot be accessed, let alone exported(`EXPORTABLE` flag) into cert. I tried a variety of less attributes, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the lack of `CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER`, according to a copyrighted PKCS11 API guide (ProtectToolkit C Programmers Manual, Copyright © Eracom Technologies), when serial number is not provided, error `CKR_WRAPPING_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID` will be returned.

Hence either add a `CKA_USAGE_COUNT` to the signing key, or indicate the serial number for the cert by indicating `CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER`/`CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER_INT` in cert template would solve the issue.

Comment: Hey, glad you got this resolved, thanks for reporting back to the site. Sorry if my suggestion didn't work; it seemed like something that could be wrong. I cannot remember seeing this error on a HSM; weird, but good info. You can accept your own answer, after a while (and I voted up of course).